# Passing an enum through a function, and be able to reassign the value returned to a variable typed as that enum

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to be able to pass an enum into a function as an argument, without having access to the enum when the function is created.

And then be able to return that enum as a value that is assignable to a variable typed as that enum.

This is what I have come up with so far, but it is not working:

```
enum TestEnum {
    VALUE = "value",
}

const takeAndReturnEnumsValueAsEnum = (e: [e: string]: string) => {
    return e
}

let testVariable: TestEnum

// this returns an error, type TestEnum is not assignable to type string
testVariable = takeAndReturnEnumsValueAsEnum(TestEnum).VALUE
```

What I have tried is finding different ways that I can pass an enum as a parameter to a function.

But all I get is that it returns type `string` or `number` instead of returning type `TestEnum`.

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the use cases for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html): we can tell TypeScript that the function return type is the same as the parameter type:

```
const takeAndReturnEnumsValueAsEnum2 = <E extends { [e: string]: string }>(e: E) => {
    return e
}

testVariable = takeAndReturnEnumsValueAsEnum2(TestEnum).VALUE
//                                                      ^? (enum member) TestEnum.VALUE = "value"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXAouaBvAUFHUBqAggDICqyUAvFAEQBuAhgDZjDUA0mAvppgMYD2IJFET0A1sAIgAJgCVgiMACcQqSPDxMWBeGuhUAFMABcUdFADaJqEiUBLEAHMAuqdsPHUTgEpKAPjNsXCUFZRAoYC4eRgURBERNe3oAIxjTOCQ9HgB6bJEACzt4KBDFFWL6cOAlJX4lNhEATwAHYFh4vSgiqBB+RCh6eHg7RxAUmJF+JtabRHsnTER4xLtxtqpRCSk5UJU9DS1JXTQDDJQ0bwA6QlJkHNyHx6eeASF+zckZeTLVNAPmI56ABMlCgAB5yMAAB5LGTFcxWNxzDyuWbzTycPxGUzIXwUAJYXAlXZVKKLZb0JKpdYicSfHY-faaAE6YGnDoXa7EMiYXJE-kCwVC4Ui-kAPQA-DwgA)

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this just blew my mind. Huge thumbs up.